# 1/4(sin^4(x))-1/6(sin^6(x)) != 1/192 (-9 cos(2 x) + cos(6 x)) yet they both have the same derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Taking the integral sin^3(x)cos^3(x) dx by hand yields, 1/4(sin^4(x))-1/6(sin^6(x)) + C. However when I [double checked](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20sin%5E3%28x%29cos%5E3%28x%29%20dx%20%3D%3D%201%2F4%28sin%5E4%28x%29%29-1%2F6%28sin%5E6%28x%29%29) my answer I was surprised to find that mathematica disagrees with me even though [taking the derivative of my answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%201%2F4%28sin%5E4%28x%29%29-1%2F6%28sin%5E6%28x%29%29) yields the original sin^3(x)cos^3(x).

Even stranger is when I take the derivative of mathematica's answer (derivative 1/192 (-9 cos(2 x) + cos(6 x))), I also get the original sin^3(x)cos^3(x).

Comment: What is your question exactly?  If you suspect wrong results, please post a clear example illustrated with valid Mathematica code.  Note that Wolfram|Alpha is off topic here.

Comment: Are you sure that the results are different? Have you tried to expand the `Cos(6x)` term for example?

Comment: I suppose the two are just different ways of expressing the same thing, this happens with trig.

Comment: @Feyre, I would expect wolfram to pick that up though. In every other case I have used trig related equality checks wolfram managed to pick it up.

Comment: Both differ by a constant, hence they're both valid antiderivates. See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin%5E3(x)cos%5E3(x)+dx+-+1%2F4(sin%5E4(x))+%2B+1%2F6(sin%5E6(x))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int1 = Integrate[Sin[x]^3 Cos[x]^3, x]

(*  -(3/64) Cos[2 x] + 1/192 Cos[6 x]  *)

int2 = 1/4 Sin[x]^4 - 1/6 Sin[x]^6 + c;

sol = Solve[int1 == int2, c][[1]] // Simplify

(*  {c -> -(1/24)}  *)
```

As expected, the two results differ by a constant, i.e., both are anti-derivatives of the integrand. Mathematica does not show an arbitrary constant in its indefinite integrals.

```
int1 == int2 /. sol // Simplify

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: That seems to be it. Thanks a lot.